# draw points on google maps in android

Tags: android, maps

I am working on Google map integration with my android application. I am able to display the map perfectly in map View. Now i need to draw points on that map based on get directions. Any working sample code will be a great help for me. I need some help in this issue. Kindly guide in.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ItemizedOverlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html) class and override draw method for drawing path.

or [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896871/google-map-driving-direction-source-code-for-their-example)