# need help in integrating google maps direction api

Tags: google-maps, directions

This is my first time in this forum.I am a fresher in website designing (i have     no knowledge abt coding) and am creating my first site using Adobe Muse.I want to integrate google maps Direction API and want it to return only the distance between two points(as exactly done in http://www.sharedcab.com . Have read many documents like https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/but could not understand how to implement.Thanks in advance and forgive me if i sound oblivious to world of coding, as i am purely in designing.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the code given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896871/google-map-driving-direction-source-code-for-their-example). Its a basic example but you can follow through.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Hi Tushar thanks a ton for the help i have figured this code out http://pastehtml.com/view/clwo7682b.txt .. only thing more i want to know is how to add form input box to the code to pass user values to the variable..thanks in advance