# Passing LatLng values in Google-maps-v3 directions API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to Pass LatLng Values for the Origin/Destination parameter in the request parameter of Directions API by Google.

Visit this link:
[Google map driving direction source code for their example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896871/google-map-driving-direction-source-code-for-their-example)

```
  var request = {
   origin: 'Chicago', // Here I want to add a latitude and Longitude value 
   destination: 'New York',
   travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
```

Comment: Use a [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest) as specified in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use a new Google lat/lng pair. For example:

```
origin: new google.maps.LatLng(51.2244, -12.12221)
```

Comment: I Already Tried That, But I had given a Bad LatLng Value. Its Working Now